# Excel How to insert a column to the right of selected cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

**Problem**

[How to insert a column to the right of a selected cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzJSt.jpg)

**What have I done?**

I googled this topic but even on Microsoft help page. I could not find any relevant information. Inserting a new column. It will always insert a column to the left of selected cell or column.

I am using

- Microsoft Excel 2013
- Windows 10

Comment: Go to give a feedback to Microsoft Excel team: https://excel.uservoice.com/

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no option to insert the column to the right in native Excel. You can only write a Macro that moves the cursor one column to the right and then inserts a new column left of itself.

Comment: This is really silly. I really appreciate you answering my question.

Comment: Unfortunately it is. Like I said, it is not that much work to create a macro that does it for you, but it is still unsatisfying that you have to do this

Answer (score 0):

Here is a macro to do what you require:

```
Sub ic2tr()
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
End Sub
```

You can assign a shortcut key to it.